# Single timestamp for multiple columns

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am using the following script to timestamp on column K any modification on column E

```
function onEdit() {
var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
if( s.getName() == "Base" )
var r = s.getActiveCell();
if( r.getColumn() == 5 )
var nextCell = r.offset(0, 6);
nextCell.setValue(new Date());
}
```

What should I do to timestamp in column K any modification on columns E to J?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the best way of doing this is with the range on the event object. Then check the sheet and if any of the columns have been edited. If so set the current date on the K column:

```js
function onEdit(e) {
  const editedRange = e.range
  const sheet = editedRange.getSheet()
  if (
    sheet.getName() === 'Base' &&
    editedRange.getLastColumn() >= 5 /*E*/ &&
    editedRange.getColumn() <= 10 /*J*/
  ) {
    const timestampRange = sheet.getRange(editedRange.getRow(), 11, editedRange.getNumRows(), 1)
    timestampRange.setValue(new Date())
  }
}
```

The basic way of working is to make sure that the edited rage is between columns `E` (5) to `J` (10) inclusive. This is done by 2 conditions:

- If the left-most column of the edited range is to the right of `J`, it's out of the range.
- If the right-most column of the edited range is to the left of `E`, then it's out of the range that we want to detect.

Note that this code sets the value to all the rows in cases where you edit multiple of them in a single operation (usually by pasting multiple rows).

### References

- [Range getColumn() (Apps Script reference)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getcolumn)
- [Range getLastColumn() (Apps Script reference)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getlastcolumn)
- [Range getNumColumns() (Apps Script reference)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getnumcolumns)
- [Range setValue(value) (Apps Script reference)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluevalue)
- [Sheet getRange(row, column, numRows, numColumns) (Apps Script reference)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column,-numrows,-numcolumns)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
function onEdit(e) {
const sh = e.source.getActiveSheet();
if( sh.getName() == "Base" && e.range.columnStart > 4 && 
e.range.columnStart < 11) {
sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart, 11).setValue(new Date())
}
```